# Dereference of a possibly null reference in child class

Tags: c#, nullable, roslyn-code-analysis, nullable-reference-types

Is it possible to tell the compiler that I *know* a method will return an object with a non-null property, even though that property is marked as nullable?

For example:

```cs
var seat = GetOccupiedSeat();
Console.WriteLine(seat.Person.Name);
// 'Person' may be null here.
// Dereference of a possibly null reference.

private Seat GetOccupiedSeat()
{
    // This method will always return a seat with a valid person and a valid name
    return new Seat(new Person("Bob"));
}

public class Seat
{
    public bool IsAvailable => Person == null;
    public Person? Person { get; set; }

    public Seat(Person? person = null)
    {
        Person = person;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

[Nullable-analysis attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) seem like the most likely things to help here, but none seem suitable to use in this context.

The kind of thing I was hoping to see was something like

```cs
[return: NotNull("Seat.Person")]
private Seat GetOccupiedSeat()
{
    return new Seat(new Person("Bob"));
}
```

Just wondering if anyone knows whether or not this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Would'nt a simple `if (seat.Person != null)` do?

Comment: @Shazi OP's intention is not to check *if* `seat.Person` is null, but *communicating* that when returned from `GetOccupiedSeat`, it *won't* be null, which is the purpose of the nullability attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, in this case.

If you're sure that it *shouldn't*, at that point in your code, you could add:

```
Debug.Assert(seat.Person is not null);
```

This will also tell the compiler to assume `seat.Person` is not null from there on, and remove the compiler warning (in Debug mode).

Comment: Good suggestion on `MemberNotNullWhenAttribute` - I had actually tried this before posting but it's only valid on properties, fields etc. `Debug.Assert` is a good shout also, but if I'm doing that, I might as well put in proper null-checking (which I probably should be doing anyway)

Comment: Doesn't seem like `[MemberNotNull(nameof(Seat.Person))]` does the job, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/PVzb1O.  Or am I misunderstanding your post?

Comment: @devklick Tbh, `Debug.Assert` is usually my go to option, when there is no other way to specify that something *shouldn't* be null at that point 1.) It's not actually null checking (I am not doing anything if it's null after all) 2.) It removes compiler warnings 3.) It makes the intent clear 4.) It's removed in production code.

Comment: @dbc I suppose it will only work if you make `GetOccupiedSeat` a member of `Seat`.

Comment: `[MemberNotNull(nameof(Person))] public static Seat GetOccupiedSeat()` doesn't seem to work if `GetOccupiedSeat()` is a static factory method, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/sKv194.

Comment: @dbc Basically, it seems to work as such, if you make `GetOccupiedSeat` an *instance* method, and call it after object instantiation, then *after* the compiler will assume that the specified member has been set. It seems it doesn't work for static methods.